# Detect whether an email is currently being edited in Outlook?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a macro that runs on the `Application_NewMail` event - but I've seen it have weird impacts if the user is currently composing an email or reply - sometimes crashing outlook and losing their progress.

Is there a way that I can detect whether the user is currently composing an email?

This would allow me to cancel the macro and avoid interrupting the user.

Comment: Have look at [DoEvents function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doevents-function)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to find bits and pieces from related questions, but nothing that took into account both the pop-up email editor and the inline-response. Here's the solution I pulled together (which seems to cover all bases):

```
Private Function IsUserEditing() As Boolean
    ' Check if the user is composing an email. Don't interrupt them if we are.
    ' 1. Check if the user has the pop-up email 'inspector' window open
    If Not (Application.ActiveInspector Is Nothing) Then
        Dim OpenWindow As Variant
        Set OpenWindow = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
        If TypeOf OpenWindow Is MailItem Then
            Dim NewMail As MailItem
            Set NewMail = OpenWindow
            ' Check if the mail they're viewing is not 'Sent' (i.e. being edited)
            If Not (NewMail.Sent) Then
                IsUserEditing = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    ' 2. Check if the user is replying to an email using the 'inline response' feature
    ElseIf Not (Application.ActiveExplorer.ActiveInlineResponse Is Nothing) Then
        IsUserEditing = True
        Exit Function
    End If
    IsUserEditing = False
End Function
```

It can be used like this:

```
Private Sub Application_NewMail()
    Debug.Print "New mail received..."        
    ' Check if the user is composing an email. Don't interrupt them if we are.
    If IsUserEditing Then
        Debug.Print "User appears to be composing an email. Cancelling..."
        Exit Sub
    End If        
    ' Otherwise Proceed
    PerformOnNewMailActions
End Sub
```

Hope this helps others!